# Why kdeplot is not normalized on its values?

Tags: python, seaborn, normalization, kdeplot

When I am using seaborn's kdeplot function I am getting a plot where the y-axis is in its actual count. I want it to show a value between 0 to 1. The kernel density normally should be between 0 and 1. But why it is still giving its actual value, what is wrong with it? I am using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
inp1 = open('1BVN_g.txt', 'r')
val = []
for line in inp1:
    #print(line)
    a = line.rstrip()
    val.append(float(a))
    
val2 = np.array(val)
sns.kdeplot(val2, shade=True)
```

Comment: I took a quick glance at the docs (<10 seconds) and think that the `hue_norm` parameter is something you should experiment with

Comment: I tried with hue_norm=True and False both. But getting the same graph. But that is again showing the same curve.

Comment: Did you read the docs? `hue_norm` doesn't accept bools as valid input

Comment: You are misinterpreting what "normalized" means.  It makes the total **area** below the curve equal to 1. The y-value can be quite high if the x-values are in a reduced range. Note that `hue_norm` is ignored here, as no `hue` is used. See [KDE on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) to get more information about a kernel density estimation.  Note that without reproducible test data and without seeing the plot you got, it is hard to know what you are doing exactly.

Comment: @PaulH You made me wondering what this parameter is really about.  It seems `hue_norm` only applies to the way lines are colored when working with a numeric hue. It has quite limited use here, as for a kdeplot needs hue needs to be restricted to a few discrete values.  An example would be `sns.kdeplot(data=tips, x='total_bill', hue='size', hue_norm=plt.Normalize(1,3))` would use the same color for table sizes 3,4,5 and 6. But it still uses different curves for each individual table size. (This reasoning is also very similar for a 2D kdeplot).